# Howto extract data from the JSON body of REST request inside a WSO2 ESB Synapse handler

Tags: java, json, wso2, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

I'm writing a custom Handler for WSO2 ESB to construct authentication credentials based on input request content. Right now what I have is something like this:

```
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext context) {
    // TODO: extract relevant information (clientId) from JSON request body
    String clientId;

    Map<String, String> headers = (Map<String, String>) ((Axis2MessageContext) context).getAxis2MessageContext().getProperty(
            org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext.TRANSPORT_HEADERS);

    setAuthorization(headers, clientId);

    return true;
}
```

I can't find documentation regarding howto access REST JSON request body inside the Synapse handler. Any ideas? Is possible to define a property before the handler runs and capture it with something like `String clientId = (String)context.getProperty("clientId")`?

Comment: can you share a full project with: API or ESB proxy, handler project for authentication, some tests to run.

Comment: I will send you personally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following;

```
// Getting the json payload to string
String jsonPayloadToString = JsonUtil.jsonPayloadToString(((Axis2MessageContext) context).getAxis2MessageContext());
// Make a json object
JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject(jsonPayloadToString);
```

Comment: on which version? as it did not work on ei 6.5.0

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
try {

        RelayUtils.buildMessage(((Axis2MessageContext) messageContext).getAxis2MessageContext());
String body = JsonUtil.jsonPayloadToString(((Axis2MessageContext) messageContext).getAxis2MessageContext());
     // here you print the body
```