# WSO2 custom handler work with JSON data

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Writing on a custom WSO2 handler my services work using JSON. Trying to get the handler read JSON data

The solve in [Howto extract data from the JSON body of REST request inside a WSO2 ESB Synapse handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35635750/howto-extract-data-from-the-json-body-of-rest-request-inside-a-wso2-esb-synapse/50487475#50487475)
did not work

[image]

Handler code

```
@Override
public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext) {

    System.out.println("getEnvelope - "+ messageContext.getEnvelope().getBody().toString());

    org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext mc = ((Axis2MessageContext) messageContext).getAxis2MessageContext();
    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject(JsonUtil.jsonPayloadToString(mc));
    System.out.println("Payload in json -"+ jsonBody);

    String jsonPayloadToString = JsonUtil.jsonPayloadToString(((Axis2MessageContext) messageContext).getAxis2MessageContext()); 
    System.out.println("Payload in string -"+ jsonPayloadToString);
```

console Output

```
getEnvelope - <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>                                                                                                                      
Payload in json -{}                                                                                                                                                                                          
Payload in string -{}
```

Tried the all 3 three combinations in axis2.xml

```
        <messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                        class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONOMBuilder"/>
        <!--messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                        class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/-->
        <!--messageBuilder contentType="application/json"
                        class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonBuilder"/-->
-----------------
        <messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                          class="org.apache.axis2.json.JSONMessageFormatter"/>
        <!--messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                          class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/-->
        <!--messageFormatter contentType="application/json"
                          class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonFormatter"/-->
```

Any help will be of great help

Thanks

Comment: Try `RelayUtils.buildMessage(messageContext);` before printing the body. And use streambuilder/formatter in axis2.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for your json:

```
try {

            RelayUtils.buildMessage(((Axis2MessageContext) messageContext).getAxis2MessageContext());
        } 
    catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    String body = JsonUtil.jsonPayloadToString(((Axis2MessageContext) messageContext).getAxis2MessageContext());
    String httpMethod = (String) ((Axis2MessageContext) messageContext).getAxis2MessageContext().getProperty("HTTP_METHOD");
    System.out.println("\n\nWSO2CustomHandler - handleRequest body!!" + body);
    System.out.println("\n\nWSO2CustomHandler - handleRequest httpMethod!!" + httpMethod);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `RelayUtils.buildMessage(messageContext);` before printing the body.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Bee

Still no luck
`org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext mc = ((Axis2MessageContext) messageContext).getAxis2MessageContext();
    RelayUtils.buildMessage(mc);
    Sysout("getEnvelope - "+ mc.getEnvelope().getBody().toString());
    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject(JsonUtil.jsonPayloadToString(mc));
    Sysout("Payload in json -"+ jsonBody);
    Sysout("Payload in xml -"+ mc);
    String jsonPayloadToString = JsonUtil.jsonPayloadToString(mc); 
    Sysout("Payload in string -"+ jsonPayloadToString);`

Comment: output
`getEnvelope - <soapenv:Body xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><jsonObject><token>8599947105184598</token></jsonObject></soapenv:Body>
Payload in json -{}
Payload in xml -[MessageContext: logID=813d1f194b272676ca200341376a57e75024074be1035574]
Payload in string -{}`
config`<messageBuilder contentType="application/json" class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>
    <messageFormatter contentType="application/json" class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonFormatter"/>`

kindly help